# Combine multiple varchar rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Col1        Col2        Col3        Col4    Col5        Col6    Col7    Col8
CH-0000001  IN-0000001  IN-0000001  ALL     NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
CH-0000001  PR-0000001  NULL        NULL    PR-0000001  ALL     NULL    NULL
CH-0000001  PU-0000001  NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL    PU-0000001  ALL
```

Hey guys I am trying to squish all this information into a single row based on a key `Col1`. I have seen a trick using `MAX` and `SUM` but it only seems to work for numbers. Here is the desired result.

```
Col1        Col3        Col4    Col5        Col6    Col7         Col8
CH-0000001  IN-0000001  ALL     PR-0000001  ALL     PU-0000001   ALL
```

Also, this problem arose from `LEFT JOIN`ing 3 tables from one master table of keys. Let me know if my approach to getting to this state is the wrong way to approach this problem. Here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM GCL_Blackboard A
LEFT JOIN GCL_Investors B ON A.Adjective_ID = B.Investor_ID
LEFT JOIN GCL_Loan_Programs C ON A.Adjective_ID = C.Program_ID
LEFT JOIN GCL_Loan_Purposes D ON A.Adjective_ID = D.Purpose_ID
```

Comment: To clarify: You want to coalesce across rows within the same column?

Comment: So, why should `col2` be `IN-0000001` instead of `PR-0000001` or `PU-0000001`?, what's the logic?

Comment: I'm sorry @Lamak col2 should have been removed from my result.

Comment: @Nicarus exactly! There will only one non-null value per column per `col1` key. It is important to remember there are more `col1` keys than shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT A.Col1,
       MIN(Col3) Col3,
       MIN(Col4) Col4 ....
FROM GCL_Blackboard A
LEFT JOIN GCL_Investors B ON A.Adjective_ID = B.Investor_ID
LEFT JOIN GCL_Loan_Programs C ON A.Adjective_ID = C.Program_ID
LEFT JOIN GCL_Loan_Purposes D ON A.Adjective_ID = D.Purpose_ID
GROUP BY A.Col1
```

Comment: Thank you Lamak!! It looks like `MAX` works also. I must of been getting the error from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
SELECT a.col1,
       max(coalesce(b.col2, c.col2, d.col2)) as col2,
       max(coalesce(b.col3, c.col3, d.col3)) as col3,
       max(coalesce(b.col4, c.col4, d.col4)) as col4,
       max(coalesce(b.col5, c.col5, d.col5)) as col5,
       max(coalesce(b.col6, c.col6, d.col6)) as col6,
       max(coalesce(b.col7, c.col7, d.col7)) as col7,
       max(coalesce(b.col8, c.col8, d.col8)) as col8
FROM GCL_Blackboard A LEFT JOIN
     GCL_Investors B
     ON A.Adjective_ID = B.Investor_ID LEFT JOIN
     GCL_Loan_Programs C
     ON A.Adjective_ID = C.Program_ID LEFT JOIN
     GCL_Loan_Purposes D
     ON A.Adjective_ID = D.Purpose_ID
GROUP BY a.col1;
```

The query is a bit of a guess, because I don't know where the columns are coming from.

Comment: how is this supposed to run with grouping only one column?

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff you are one of the most helpful people when it comes to SQL.